# Angular 7 reactive form is always invalid when using css to autocapitalize a required field unless user uses capslock and shift key

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-reactive-forms, angular7

I have the following input which should auto-capitalize letters A, B and C, without letting the user use the capslock or shift+letter.

The input is within a reactive form:

```
SignupForm: FormGroup;
  ngOnInit(){
    this.SignupForm = new FormGroup({
      'username': new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('[A-C ]*'))
    });
}
```

And here is the html form:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1">
      <form [formGroup]="SignupForm">
             <label for="username">UserName</label>
             <input type="text" class="form-control autoCapitalise"
              id="username" formControlName = "username">
              {{SignupForm.controls.username.error || JSON}}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
.autoCapitalise{
  text-transform: uppercase
}
```

Now the user when typing few letters, the autocapitalize is working, but the form still invalid, until the user again uses the capslock or the shift key.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-3idenk) to describe the problem better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize) - The autocapitalize attribute doesn’t affect behavior when typing on a physical keyboard

You can change the value base on valueChanges everytime the user enter any value will change to uppercase

```
this.SignupForm.get('username').valueChanges
.pipe(distinct())
  .subscribe(value => {
    this.SignupForm.get('username').setValue(value.toUpperCase());
  })
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53553748)